# choosing multiple items in the same drop-down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Here is part of the view in question. I'm trying to do this with `multiple: true` option, but when selecting one item then another, the checkbox only shows up just by the last item that I selected.

```
  <%= f.fields_for :event_artists do |fea| %>
    <%= fea.select(:artist_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Artist.all, "id", "name"), multiple: true) %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: i think you should use gem "select2-rails" it make easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add  :input_html => {:size => 10 }  so it looks like -

```
<%= f.fields_for :event_artists do |fea| %>
    <%= fea.select(:artist_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Artist.all, "id", "name"), multiple: true,  :input_html => {:size => 10 }) %>
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ..."id", "name"), multiple: true), :input_html => { :size => 10... ... ^` not seeing where the error is, though

Comment: Just need to put the input_html inside the param. Updated the answer

Comment: the page loads okay now, but the dropdown still allows only one selection

Comment: ok, I'm seeing some stuff in another thread about `options_select_for` + `multiple: true` combo that says that you have hold down command/ctrl button to select multiple options. the dropdown closes after only selecting one, so it looks like this way was not even intended for the drop-down menu to begin with?

Comment: as far as I can tell, this is related to the `artist_id` column type being integer, not string and an array (because for `multiple: true` show up in view source, pg should expect an array, not an integer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array if you want to show already selected values in dropdown.

```
<%= f.fields_for :event_artists do |fea| %>
  <%= fea.select(:artist_id, 
                 options_from_collection_for_select(Artist.all, "id", "name", [1,2,3]), 
                 multiple: true) %>
<% end %>
```

Remember to change the array `[1,2,3,4]` with your artist values  something like `@event_artist.artist_ids`

Comment: the `Artist.all, "id", "name"` part alone takes care of that though, the artists do show up in the drop down, I just can't select more than one of them